# UICollectionViewCell created from XIB will cause flickering during drag and drop

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I implement a simple drag and drop sample.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    private var collectionView: UICollectionView?
    
    var colors: [UIColor] = [
        .link,
        .systemGreen,
        .systemBlue,
        .red,
        .systemOrange,
        .black,
        .systemPurple,
        .systemYellow,
        .systemPink,
        .link,
        .systemGreen,
        .systemBlue,
        .red,
        .systemOrange,
        .black,
        .systemPurple,
        .systemYellow,
        .systemPink
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width/3.2, height: view.frame.size.width/3.2)
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        
        //collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        
        let customCollectionViewCellNib = CustomCollectionViewCell.getUINib()
        collectionView?.register(customCollectionViewCellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        
        collectionView?.delegate = self
        collectionView?.dataSource = self
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(collectionView!)
        
        let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPressGesture))
        collectionView?.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

    @objc func handleLongPressGesture(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return
        }
        
        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            guard let targetIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: self.collectionView)) else {
                return
            }
            collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: targetIndexPath)
        case .changed:
            collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: collectionView))
        case .ended:
            collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
        default:
            collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        collectionView?.frame = view.bounds
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return colors.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        
        cell.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width/3.2, height: view.frame.size.width/3.2)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        let item = colors.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        colors.insert(item, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }
}
```

However, I notice that, if my `UICollectionViewCell` is created with XIB, it will randomly exhibit flickering behaviour, during drag and drop.

---

The `CustomCollectionViewCell` is a pretty straightforward code.

## CustomCollectionViewCell.swift

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    static func instanceFromNib() -> Self {
        return getUINib().instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! Self
    }
    
    static func getUINib() -> UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: String(describing: self), bundle: nil)
    }
}


class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

}
```

---

## Flickering

By using the following code

```
let customCollectionViewCellNib = CustomCollectionViewCell.getUINib()
collectionView?.register(customCollectionViewCellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

It will have the following random flickering behaviour - https://youtu.be/CbcUAHlRJKI

---

## No flickering

However, if the following code is used instead

```
collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Things work fine. There are no flickering behaviour - https://youtu.be/QkV2HlIrXK8

---

May I know why it is so? How can I avoid the flickering behaviour, when my custom `UICollectionView` is created from XIB?

Please note that, the flickering behaviour doesn't happen all the time. It happens randomly. It is easier to reproduce the problem using real iPhone device, than simulator.

Here's the complete sample code - https://github.com/yccheok/xib-view-cell-cause-flickering

Answer (score 2):

While we are rearranging cells in `UICollectionView` (gesture is active), it handles all of the cell movements for us (without having us to worry about changing `dataSource` while the rearrange is in flight).

At the end of this rearrange gesture, `UICollectionView` rightfully expects that we will reflect the change in our `dataSource` as well which you are doing correctly here.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item = colors.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    colors.insert(item, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
}
```

---

Since `UICollectionView` expects a `dataSource` update from our side, it performs following steps -

1. Call our `collectionView(_:, moveItemAt:, to:)` implementation to provide us a chance to reflect the changes in `dataSource`.
2. Call our `collectionView(_:, cellForItemAt:)` implementation for the `destinationIndexPath`  value from call `#1`, to re-create a new cell at that indexPath from scratch.

###### Okay, but why would it perform step 2 even if this is the correct cell to be at that indexPath?

> It's because `UICollectionView` **doesn't know for sure** whether you actually made those `dataSource` changes or not. What happens if you don't make those changes? - now your `dataSource` & `UI` are out of sync.
>
> In order to make sure that your `dataSource` changes are correctly reflected in the `UI`, it has to do this step.

Now when the cell is being re-created, you *sometimes* see the flicker. Let the UI reload the first time, put a breakpoint in the `cellForItemAt:` implementation at the first line and rearrange a cell. Right after rearrange completes, your program will pause at that breakpoint and you can see following on the screen.
[image]

---

###### Why does it not happen with `UICollectionViewCell` class (not XIB)?

> It does (as noted by others) - it's less frequent. Using the above steps by putting a breakpoint, you can catch it in that state.

---

###### How to solve this?

1. Get a reference to the cell that's currently being dragged.
2. Return this instance from `cellForItemAt:` implementation.

```
var currentlyBeingDraggedCell: UICollectionViewCell?
var willRecreateCellAtDraggedIndexPath: Bool = false
@objc func handleLongPressGesture(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let cv = collectionView else { return }
    
    let location = gesture.location(in: cv)
    switch gesture.state {
    case .began:
        guard let targetIndexPath = cv.indexPathForItem(at: location) else { return }
        currentlyBeingDraggedCell = cv.cellForItem(at: targetIndexPath)
        cv.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: targetIndexPath)
        
    case .changed:
        cv.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(location)
        
    case .ended:
        willRecreateCellAtDraggedIndexPath = true
        cv.endInteractiveMovement()
    
    default:
        cv.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    }
}
```

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    if willRecreateCellAtDraggedIndexPath,
       let currentlyBeingDraggedCell = currentlyBeingDraggedCell {
        self.willRecreateCellAtDraggedIndexPath = false
        self.currentlyBeingDraggedCell = nil
        return currentlyBeingDraggedCell
    }
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.item]
        
    return cell
}
```

---

##### Will this solve the problem 100%?

> NO. `UICollectionView` will still remove the cell from it's view hierarchy and ask us for a new cell - we are just providing it with an existing cell instance (that we know is going to be correct according to our own implementation).
>
> You can still catch it in the state where it disappears from UI before appearing again. However this time there's almost no work to be done, so it will be significantly faster and you will see the flickering less often.

---

##### BONUS

**iOS 15** seems to be working on similar problems via [UICollectionView.reconfigureItems](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/3801889-reconfigureitems) APIs. See an explanation in following Twitter thread.
[image]
Whether these improvements will land in rearrange or not, we will have to see.

---

##### Other Observations

Your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass' XIB looks like following
[image]

However it should look like following (1st one is missing **contentView** wrapper, you get this by default when you drag a `Collection View Cell` to the XIB from the View library OR create a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass with XIB).
[image]

And your implementation uses -

```
cell.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.row]
```

You should use **contentView** to do all the UI customization, also note the `indexPath.item`(vs `row`) that better fits with `cellForItemAt:` terminology (There are no differences in these values though). `cellForRowAt:` & `indexPath.row` are more suited for `UITableView` instances.

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.item]
```

---

#### UPDATE

###### Should I use this workaround for my app in production?

> NO.

As noted by OP in the comments below -

> The proposed workaround has 2 shortcomings.
>
> **(1) Missing cell**
>
> **(2) Wrong content cell.**
>
> This is clearly visible in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDRgo0Jczuw Even if you perform explicit `currentlyBeingDraggedCell.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.item]` within `if` block, wrong content cell issue is still there.

---

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. However, if I create UICollectionViewCell subclass from XIB, I do not get the "contentView" as shown in https://imgur.com/a/s3olpZ7 . Do you know why?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng You can delete this cell from XIB, manually drag a new `Collection View Cell` from the view library and set it's class to the correct subclass. See this - https://imgur.com/4Yt4GjA

Comment: I never know this till I read on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcell/1620133-contentview . So far, I still not encounter any issue of not using contentView. Do you know why Xcode default XIB creation behaviour doesn't place contentView in UICollectionViewCell?

Comment: To be honest, I'm a bit surprised that `UICollectionViewCell` subclass (when created with XIB) doesn't create the expected `contentView` wrapper in the XIB as intended. You have `contentView` in both `UITableViewCell` & `UICollectionViewCell` sublcasses.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate that you're informing me regarding the contentView. I will investigate further.

Comment: After I did some testing, I feel it is Ok to use the default XIB with only safeArea. I guess even if the contentView is not visible in XIB, the components added under safeArea will place in contentView implicit. I confirm my finding, to print out `cell.contentView.subviews.count`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, please do note that, the proposed workaround do have 2 shortcomings. (1) Missing cell (2) Wrong content cell. This can shown in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDRgo0Jczuw Even I perform explicit `currentlyBeingDraggedCell.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.row]` within `if` block, wrong content cell issue still there.

Comment: Well it is what it is - you now have a clear understanding of why it is flickering. This is a workaround and NOT a solution. In fact it creates more issues like you mentioned above. We can't change this behavior in `UICollectionView`. Recreate will happen after drop and it will inconsistently flicker as well. I have provided this information in the **UPDATE** to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The flickering is caused by the cell being recreated at its new position. You can try holding to the cell.

(only the relevant code is shown)

```swift
// keeps a reference to the cell being dragged
private weak var draggedCell: UICollectionViewCell?
// the flag is set when the dragging completes
private var didInteractiveMovementEnd = false

@objc func handleLongPressGesture(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.state {
    case .began:
        // keep cell reference
        draggedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: targetIndexPath)
        collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: targetIndexPath)

    case .ended:
        // reuse the cell in `cellForItem`
        didInteractiveMovementEnd = true
        collectionView.performBatchUpdates {
            collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
        } completion: { completed in
            self.draggedCell = nil
            self.didInteractiveMovementEnd = false
        }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // reuse the dragged cell
    if didInteractiveMovementEnd, let draggedCell = draggedCell {
        return draggedCell
    }
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, please do note that, the proposed workaround do have 2 shortcomings. (1) Missing cell (2) Wrong content cell. This can shown in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDRgo0Jczuw Even I perform explicit `draggedCell.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.row]` within `if` block, wrong content cell issue still there.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng I do not see these issues with the code I've posted. You can update your code repository with your changes for review.